# What is the difference between company direct hiring and through consultancy involvement hiring?

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment

I got selected in an American multinational corporation through consultancy involvement that means consultancy arrange interviews with them and they released offer letter to me.

Is this a secure job?

What is the difference between company direct hiring and through consultancy involvement hiring?

Answer (score 4):

> What is the difference between company direct hiring and through consultancy involvement hiring?

Since they are giving you the offer letter, you are directly employed by them rather than employed through a 3rd party consultancy that contracts employment with them. It's likely they have a recruiting relationship with hiring consultancy you've been working with (typically known as a headhunter). For example, the headhunter brings the company candidates. If a candidate that headhunter brings is hired, the headhunter is given a percentage of your hiring salary. The exact way the headhunter is compensated depends on their contract with the company, but generally you, the job candidate, are not affected monetarily by this relationship. For more information, see [Headhunters, Recruiters, and Hiring Managers—What's the Difference?](https://www.themuse.com/advice/headhunters-recruiters-and-hiring-managerswhats-the-difference)

Comment: is there any diff b/w me and direct hired person by CTS with out consultancy ?

Comment: How will consultancy get benefits by me?.Why company ask consultancy to involve this recruitment process?

Comment: A company may hire a recruiting firm because 1) there is no in-house recruiter, 2) the position is difficult to fill, 3) high number of open positions, 4) the position is not publicized or 5) executive search. There maybe be more reasons why to use one, but ultimately, it doesn't really affect you as the job candidate.

Comment: As you said above i am not related to headhunter relationship and i am permanent employee with Cognizant.So i need not worry

Comment: *How will consultancy get benefits by me?* - the consulting firm is typically paid a fee by the employer.

Answer (score 1):

This is common. There's nothing strange or sketchy about it. A consultancy (or recruiting agency) found you and presented you to this employer. The employer decided to hire you and gave you a job offer.

Your employer will, very likely, pay a fee to the consultancy when you begin working. But that is between them. You don't need to do anything at all about that.

Another person might send their resume directly to the employer and be hired. In that case the employer (usually) owes no fee to any agency.

You should be sure of this, however. If you haven't already done so, read the offer letter carefully. It says, clearly, who will hire you.